# how to change ubuntu display name?

Tags: amazon-ec2, ubuntu-16.04

I'm wondering how I can change the displaying name when I log into my server.

So for example I SSH into the server and it display my username @ ec2 instance ip.

```
example: username@ip-10.0.0.129

what I want: username@production
```

I don't want it to affect any DNS, host, hostname or Ip stuff only to give it a nickname, any suggestions?

another example: When Cron finishes its job it sends an email from root

```
Cron <root@ip-10-0-0-129>.....

what I want: Cron <root@production>.....
```

My ec2 instance on aws is called production so could I somehow instead tell the system to use that name instead of the ip address?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to customize your bash prompt settings in your ~/.bashrc file and change the value of the PS1 variable that controls the presentation of the bash prompt.  There are many examples of how to do this online but here is [one](https://www.howtogeek.com/307701/how-to-customize-and-colorize-your-bash-prompt/).

If you want to hardcode it to your username@production, you can do something like this:

```
PS1='\u@production: '
```

You can test this first right from your bash prompt before editing the bashrc file, i.e. just enter what I have above, so something like this:

```
DEFAULT=$PS1 #save your existing setting
PS1='\u@production: ' #try a new setting
PS1=$DEFAULT #restore the original setting
```

You can also just edit the hostname of your system as detailed in the AWS documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/set-hostname.html).